# jmeter mail reader sampler - controlling which msgs to fetch

Tags: email, jmeter

I have jmeter's mail reader sampler working and it fetches the email from my gmail account. The issue is that it keeps fetching the email from the oldest to newest manner and I have about ~10k messsages in my email.

So when I specify get 5 messages, it keeps fetching the oldest five messages in my email. Is there a way I can make it fetch only the latest 5 messages for me without making it fetch all ~10k messages in the process?

One more question: what if I want it to only fetch a message that has a certain keyword like this below, regardless of whether its in the latest 100 or latest 5 messages, especially as I keep getting emails throughout the day:

```
key "generated_key" (there is text preceding it and after it)
```

Can you tell me how I could make that work. Thank you!

Comment: I don't think it's possible. But you can read a folder that only has messages you need. Which means that either you move messages you want to read under a separate folder, or you move all messages you don't want to read from INBOX folder.

Comment: Sounds good, thanks! I ended up creating another email address and then started using that, instead.